# Asp.net Mvc using Json How to Edit the Record

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am creating a simple crud system in Asp.net MVC using json. i need to update the record. but i don't how to do it. i successfully view the data from database and passing to Datatable. and Successfully add the records. when i Edit the record i don't know how to pass the values from the controller what i tried so far i written below.Edit(int Id) i just tried like this way.data is not passing to the relavent textboxes for edit.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRi39.jpg)

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: /Home/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    lgschoolEntities1 dc = new lgschoolEntities1();

    public ActionResult GetStudents()
    {
        using (lgschoolEntities1 db = new lgschoolEntities1())
        {
            var student = db.courses.ToList();
            return Json(new { data = student }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);        
         }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(course cou)
    {
        bool status = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (lgschoolEntities1 dc = new lgschoolEntities1())
            {
                if (cou.id > 0)
                {
                    //Edit 
                    var v = dc.courses.Where(a => a.id == cou.id).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (v != null)
                    {
                        v.name = cou.name;
                        v.course1 = cou.course1;                 
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Save
                    dc.courses.Add(cou);
                }
                dc.SaveChanges();
                status = true;
            }
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int Id)
    {
        //Get the student from studentList sample collection for demo purpose.
        //Get the student from the database in the real application
        var std = dc.courses.Where(a => a.id == Id).FirstOrDefault();


        return new JsonResult { Data = new { std = std } };

     }
```

Below the code i wrote for view the records from the database.when i view the record if i want to edit the record click edit button relavent data will be passing to the relvent textbooxs for edit.

```
function get_all() {
    $('#tbl-category').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    var oTable = $('#tbl-category').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": '/home/GetStudents',
            "type": "get",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name", "200px": true },
            { "data": "course1", "200px": true },

            {
                "data": "id", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {

                     return '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick="get_category_details(' + data + ')  ">Edit</button>';
                 }
             },
             {
                 "data": "id", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {

                     return '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" onclick="RemoveCategory(' + data + ')">Delete</button>';

                  }
              }
          ]
     })

 }
```

i am doing Add and Edit both doing at the Same Function.

```
 function addProject() {
     var _url = '';
     var _data = '';
     var _method;   
     if (isNew == true) {
         _url = '/home/Save';
         _data = "{name: '" + $('#name').val() + "',course1: '" + $('#course1').val() + "'}";
        _method = 'POST';
     }
     else {
         _url = '/home/Edit',
         //    _data = "{fname: '" + $('#fname').val() + "',age: '" + $('#age').val() + "', id: '" + id + "'}";
         _data = "{fname: '" + $('#fname').val() + "', age: '" + $('#age').val() + "', id:'" + ID + "'}";
         _method = 'POST';
     }
     console.log(_data);
     $.ajax({
         type: _method,
         url: _url,
         dataType: 'JSON',
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         data: _data,

         success: function (data) {

             alert("Success");

             get_all();
             $('#name').val("");
             $('#course1').val("");
             $('#name').focus();


             var msg;
             if (isNew) {
                 msg = "Data Created";

             }
             else {
                 msg = "Update Created";

             }
             $.alert({
                 title: 'Success!',
                 content: msg,
                 type: 'green',
                 boxWidth: '400px',
                 theme: 'light',
                 useBootstrap: false,
                 autoClose: 'ok|2000'
             });
         }
     });
 }
```

this how i am passing the values to the relavent textboxs when i click the edit button .

```
function get_category_details(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  '/home/Edit',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: "{id: '" + id + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            //      $('body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
            isNew = false;

            ID = data.d[0].id;
            $('#id').attr('value', data.d[0].id);
            $('#name').attr('value', data.d[0].name);
            $('#course1').attr('value', data.d[0].course1);


        }
    });
}
```

**Form**

```
<div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("save","home", FormMethod.Post, new { id= "popupForm" }))
    { 
         <div class="card-panel teal lighten-2 white-text" align="center">
             <h4> Registation</h4>
         </div>

         <div class="card-action">

         <label class="form-label">Name</label>

         <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required />

         </div>
         <div class="card-action">
             <label class="form-label">Course</label>
             <input type="text" id="course1" name="course1" class="form-control" placeholder="Course" required />
         </div>

         <div class="card" align="center">
             <button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-info" onclick="addProject()">
                 Registation
             </button>
         </div>

     }
 </div>

 <div class="col s12 m6 offset-m4">
     <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">Current Team Members</h3>
     </div>

     <div class="panel-body">

         <table id="tbl-category" style="width:90%; margin:0 auto">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th>Name</th>
                     <th>Course</th>

                     <th>Edit</th>
                     <th>Delete</th>
                 </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**this is the error displayed when i break point**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRi39.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already doing it right just that you need to tell `Entity Framework` that the model has been changed, you do that by setting the model state, change the state to `EntityState.Modified`

like as below

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(course cou)
    {
        bool status = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (lgschoolEntities1 dc = new lgschoolEntities1())
            {
                if (cou.id > 0)
                {
                    //Edit 
                    var v = dc.courses.Where(a => a.id == cou.id).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (v != null)
                    {
                        v.name = cou.name;
                        v.course1 = cou.course1;    
                        //you just need to add this line
                        dc.Entry(v).State = EntityState.Modified;             
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Save
                    dc.courses.Add(cou);
                }
                dc.SaveChanges();
                status = true;
            }
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };

    }
```

When you are doing `dc.Entry(v).State = EntityState.Modified;`, you are not only attaching the entity to you database context, you are also marking the whole entity as dirty and updated. This means that when you do context.SaveChanges(), EF will generate an update statement that will update all the fields of the entity.

So Editing also means updating the records in the Db

Also look at some details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state)

**EDIT**
Also change the javascript function to

```
function addProject() {
        var _url = '';
        var _data = '';
        var _method;   
        if (isNew == true) {
            _url = '/home/Save';
            _data = "{name: '" + $('#name').val() + "',course1: '" + $('#course1').val() + "'}";
            _method = 'POST';
        }
        else {
            _url = '/home/Save', //Change this line because you are using thte same method to save and edit in your controller
            //    _data = "{fname: '" + $('#fname').val() + "',age: '" + $('#age').val() + "', id: '" + id + "'}";
            _data = "{fname: '" + $('#fname').val() + "', age: '" + $('#age').val() + "', id:'" + ID + "'}";
            _method = 'POST';
        }
        console.log(_data);

        //You ajax call here
        //The code below was commented to keep answer short
    }

    [HttpGet] //Change to get
    public JsonResult Edit(int Id)
    {
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { std = std } };
    }
```

Also change the way you call it in your javascript and the way you assign the variables

```
function get_category_details(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:  '/home/Edit?Id=' + id,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                  console.log(data);
                //      $('body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
                isNew = false;

                ID = data.id;
                $('#id').val(data.id);
                $('#name').val(data.name);
                $('#course1').val(data.course1);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: i emailed it sir .without database.can you check it sir

Comment: yes sir it good well thanks alot. can you do the delete stuff for me sir