# Edit image delete old image file or replace image

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am uploading an image to a folder and saving the details in a SQL database. This is all working fine, but when editing how do I delete the old file or maybe simply override the old file with the new one? Here is the code for the add and edit:

Thanks,
EB

Add:

```
[HttpPost]
                        public ActionResult AddDocument(Document newDocument, HttpPostedFileBase file)
                        {
                            string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                            string filePath = "/Documents/" + newDocument.Department + "/" + fileName;
                            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));

                            db.Documents.Add(new Document
                            {
                                DocumentName = fileName,
                                Document_url = filePath,
                                Department = newDocument.Department,
                                DocumentType = fileExtension,
                                Description = newDocument.Description
                            }
                                );
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            return RedirectToAction("Index");
                        }
```

Edit:

```
                         [HttpPost]
                                public ActionResult EditDocument(int id, Document document)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        db.Entry(document).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                                        db.SaveChanges();
                                        return RedirectToAction("DocumentDetails", new { id = id });
                                    }
                                    catch
                                    {
                                        return View();
                                    }
                                }


                         [HttpPost]
                                public ActionResult EditDocument(int id, Document document)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        db.Entry(document).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                                        db.SaveChanges();
                                        return RedirectToAction("DocumentDetails", new { id = id });
                                    }
                                    catch
                                    {
                                        return View();
                                    }
                                }
```

Comment: in the edit action, delete the file from disk (or you can keep it for history keeping if you'd like)- you know the location of the current file from `document.Document_url`. Then assign the new `file` data to `document` although youre not passing in any `file` to the edit action so that's a problem in itself. Also, you are saving the file name to disk by the name of the file the user uploads- what happens if 2 users upload a file named the same thing? It's safer to save the metadata to the db, then write the file to disk and name it via it's primary key in the db (`id`).

Comment: @GregH you are right. To delete the old file you can also define an attribute and decorate the Edit methid with it. In that attribute you have the id of the image that have been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way you can do it.

```
public ActionResult EditDocument(int id, Document document, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{            
    //NOTE that you only need one of the parameters id or document, my example is using document
    try
    {
        string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        string filePath = "/Docs/" + document.Department + "/" + fileName;
        document.DocumentType = fileExtension;
        document.Document_url= filePath;
        document.DocumentName = fileName;

        var oldDocument = db.Documents.First(m => m.Id == document.Id);
        //or var oldDocument = db.Documents.First(m => m.Id == id); //if that is how you get the id
            //you can delete the file here or leave it in storage never referenced in the db
            FileInfo myfileinf = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(oldDocument.Document_url));
        //check if file exists before deleting
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(myfileinf.FullName))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(myfileinf.FullName);
        }
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));
        //set the old document here
        db.Entry(oldDocument).CurrentValues.SetValues(document);
        db.Entry(oldDocument).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("EditDocument", new { id = id });
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

You can also look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863029/asp-net-mvc-using-json-how-to-edit-the-record/56863181#56863181) and see if it helps